# Efficient sparse matrix addition in Armadillo

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, armadillo

I am trying to construct a sparse matrix L of the form
[image]
[image]

`L` and `Hi` are respectively a very sparse matrix and row vector. The final L matrix should have a density of around 1 % .

Armadillo provides a `arma::sp_mat` class that seems to suit my needs. The assembly of `L` then looks like this

```
    arma::sp_mat L(N,N);
    arma::sp_mat Hi(1,N);

    for (int i = 0; i < p; ++ i){

    // The non-zero terms in Hi are populated here

    L += Hi.t() * Hi;

    }
```

The number of non-zero elements in `Hi` is constant with `i`. I do not have much experience with sparse matrices but I was expecting the incremental assembly of `L` to be relatively constant in speed.

Yet, it seems that the speed at which `Hi.t() * Hi` is added to `L` decreases over time. Am I doing something wrong in the way I assemble `L`? Should I preconstruct `L` by specifying which of its components I know will not be zero?

Comment: Which version of Armadillo are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `L` is not initialized so that it effectively changes size when incremented with `Hi.t() * Hi`. This was likely the cause for the decrease in the speed.